# How can we make few tokens to be phrase in elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, token, phrase, booleanquery, elasticsearch-analyzers

I want to search part of query to be considered as phrase .For e.g. I want to search "Can you show me documents for Hospitality and Airline Industry"
Here I want Airline Industry to be considered as phrase.I dont find any such settings in multi_match .
Even when we try to use multi_match query using "Can you show me documents for Hospitality and \"Airline Industry\"" .Default analyser breaks it into separate tokens.I dont want to change settings of my analyser.Also I have found that we can do this in simple_query_string but that has consequences that we can not apply filter option as we have in multi_match boolean query because I want to apply filter on certain feilds as well.

search_text="Can you show me documents for Hospitality and Airline Industry"  Now I Want to pass Airline Industry as a phrase to search my indexed document against 2 fields.
okay so say I have existing code like this.

```
If filter:
qry={
    “query":{
        “bool”:{
            “must”:{
                "multi_match":{
                "query":search_text,
                "type":"best_fields",
                "fields":["TITLE1","TEXT"],
                "tie_breaker":0.3,
                }
            },
            “filter”:{“terms”:{“GRP_CD”:[“1234”,”5678”]     }
    }
    }

else:
qry={

    "query":{
        "multi_match":{
        "query":search_text',
        "type":"best_fields",
        "fields":["TITLE1",TEXT"],
        "tie_breaker":0.3
        }
    }
}
```

'But then I have realised this code is not handling Airline Industry as a phrase even though I am passing search string like this
"Can you show me documents for Hospitality and \"Airline Industry\""

As per elastic search document I came to know there is this query which might handle this

```
qry={"query":{
"simple_query_string":{
"query":"Can you show me documents for Hospitality and \"Airline Industry\"",
"fields":["TITLE1","TEXT"] }
} }
```

But now my issue is what if user want to apply filter..with filter query as above I can not pass phrase and boolean query is not possible with simple_query_string'

Comment: `simple_query_string` is the one of the correct choice but what filters you wont be able to apply if using `simple_query_string`. Can you explain with e.g.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always combine queries using [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). Lets understand this case by case. Before going to the cases I would like to clarify one thing which is about filter. The filter clause of boolean query behave just like a must clause but the difference is that any query (even another boolean query with a must/should clause(s)) inside filter clause have filter context. Filter context means, that part of query will not be considered for score calculation.

Now lets move on to cases:

#### Case 1: Only query and no filters.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "Can you show me documents for Hospitality and \"Airline Industry\"",
            "fields": [
              "TITLE1",
              "TEXT"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the query is same as specified by you in the question. All I have done here is that I wrapped it in a bool query. This doesn't make any logical change to the query but doing so will make it easier to add queries to filter clause programmatically.

#### Case 2: Phrase query with filter.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "Can you show me documents for Hospitality and \"Airline Industry\"",
            "fields": [
              "TITLE1",
              "TEXT"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "GRP_CD": [
              "1234",
              "5678"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can combine query(query context) with the filters.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.I will try these queries given by you.BTW do you also agree that multi_match doesnt handle partial phrase right and simple_query_string is the only option?Sorry but I am a newbie in elastic search.

Comment: You can do full phrase search but not partial. For e.g. when searching for a string **quick brown fox** you can search this whole string as a phrase but if you want only **brown fox** for the complete string as a phrase and rest as normal query string then that can not be done using a single `multi_match` query.